# Sharepoint 2010 content types?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am a newbie working on Sharepoint 2010 & trying to find out what all properties or metadata available for content items stored in it.

Till now i could find that GUID is one of them providing unique id for content but i am interested in what all properties available in it with syntax of properties e.g. sp:name or something else.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the official list of properties/methods that are members of the SPListItem class. Then you can any number of additional fields (properties) available for yours items if you add them to the list of the content type it is using.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_members(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also need properties of site content such as doc or pdf stored in site. Can you help?